# Bootstrap 4 .btn-default для webkit

Tags: css, bootstrap

Проблема: некорректно отображаются `bootstrap` кнопки:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<li>
  <div class="col-xs-3 m-1">
    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
        Login
    </button>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="col-xs-3 m-1">
    <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
        Register
    </button>
  </div>
</li>
```

ОС: iOS 10, браузер: Chrome
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ОС: Win10, браузер: Chrome
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Chrome под Android - тоже все корректно.
P. S. Пробовал `class="btn"`, `class="btn btn-default"` - тот же результат.
UPDATE: `btn-secondary` отображается корректно. Не могу понять, почему `btn-default` не отображается. [Отсюда](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#buttons): "Renamed .btn-default to .btn-secondary." Но `.btn-default` поддерживается ведь...

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

на кнопки поставь, вроде должно помочь